# How to set different web authentication mode for different database in Lotus Domino

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, lotus-domino, web-access

Disclaimer: I'm not a Notes admin, I just wrote the application :), and I try to help our client to use it.

We provide a simple database with one agent to accept and process HTTP POST messages from Internet.

The Domino server where this database is going to be installed is configured for Single SignOn authentication for web access.

Is there a way so set only our database to use different type of authentication - i.e. Basic Authentication, so we can hit it like this to POST messages to the agent:

http://username:password@my.domino.server/mydb.nsf/myagent

I thought about another approach as well - to remove any form of auth, and pass the credentials in the POSTed data itself. Then the agent will take care to process or not the data, base on if the creds are OK. But this most probably will require some form of "impersonation" - I.e. to map somehow the anonymous user to the one, which has the rights to execute the agent. So, I valid answer to this question may be an advise how to set this up.

Additionally - we are looking at the web service approach (available in Domino 7.0+), but it will require changes on both sides - the sender (our publisher service) and the receiving agent. And most probably will lead back to the original question about how to authenticate the sender.

Any advice in that regard (even changing the approach) will be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Domino 7.0.2 there is a new kind of website rule entitled "Override Session Authentication" that allows you to specify, for a specific URL pattern (ex : /folder/myapp.nsf/myagent?*) to use BASIC auth even if the whole server is configured for session-based auth.

This was initially introduced for RSS readers (that cannot handle sessions).

More information here :
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_OVERRIDING_SESSION_AUTHENTICATION_8847_STEPS.html

Answer (score 2):

Although it's horribly insecure to allow this, it is possible using web site documents on the server.

Create a website document that has basic authentication for your database (it will need it's own domain name) and then everyone else can access the server through the default website document which uses session authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding **Anonymous** to the ACL of the database, with **No access** and nothing but **Read public documents** checked. Then, you can grant access to the agent by checking **Allow Public Access users to view and run this agent** in the Agent properties.

I don't know if it is possible to get the `Authorization` header into the agent to check the authentication. If there are only two parties communicating I would compute a hash of the message, a timestamp and a shared secret and use that to check access.

**Edit**

You won't be able to parse the `Authorization` header manually. Domino (at least 7.0.3) tries to do a session authentication if your request contains an authorization header, regardless of access settings on the object you request.

Comment: Anders is the 'Authorization' header documented anywhere? Google ain't bringing much on it for Domino.

Comment: Oh that! I thought this was some Domino speciality which would help me force Basic Auth even if not enabled on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here, put that URL in your Favorites toolbar :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/welcome_Domino_8_5_3.html

Also did you know that your Notes client and Domino Server come with help databases full of very adequate documents ? Try the [Help] menu for starters.

Then, said help databases are usually in the aptlty named "help" folder". Open them.