# Authentication and web services in Domino?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is there a way to allow authentication in Domino webservices?  If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IBM has an example [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295968). There are [other](http://www.nsftools.com/stubby/Authentication.htm) [options](http://www.garydev.com/gdev/garydevnew.nsf/d6plinks/GDEF-6APUBS).

Comment: Could link to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055585/401236) for options on basic authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Another way in JAVA would be:

```
ServiceBindingStub stub = (WebServiceBindingStub) new ServiceLocator().getWebServicePort(portAddress);
stub.setSSLOptions(PortTypeBase.NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS + PortTypeBase.NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_EXPIRED_CERTS);

stub.setUsername(usr);
stub.setPassword(pwd);
```