# Java Web Services Authentication Lotus Notes

Tags: java, web-services, basic-authentication, lotus-domino, lotus

I want to implement very simple java based web service (Provider) in domino... say print "Hello World"

But this has to first authenticate/authorize the user i.e

login 
user present in names.nsf
valid password
access in Db etc.

In short we can say domino login functionality.

Hope u understand the requirement. So I want Hello world to be printed only if user authenticated successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication and web services in Domino?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539408/authentication-and-web-services-in-domino)

Answer (score 4):

The authentication is handled by the ACL of the database. The user mentioned in the ACL needs an internet password in their person document.

Once that is set up, your consumer needs to specify the user/password in the stub.

For example, I created a provider called "ws":

```
Ws stub = new WsServiceLocator().getDomino();
stub.setCredentials("user", "password");
stub.HELLO("world");
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your reply. How can I use my provider after this.

Comment: Hi Simon, 

Thanks for your reply. How can I use my provider after this.

For example, 

I have a java application where I have 4 fields Username,password,Value "1" and Value "2". 

User will enter his Lotus Notes web user name in field 1 password in field 2 & two integers (say 2,4) in rest two fields& then click add. Then I want to call a web service which will check if valid username & password is provided & if user is authenticated the addition of 2 numbers will be return. Can you please let me know how can i achieve this? I really need this very urgently.

Comment: The sample above is calling the provider with the "HELLO" method (provider API call). Your response sounds like a different question, or needs to be in better detail in the main question.

Comment: Ok. I will try to execute it let put my comments with output. BTW I am really thankful for your help.